# Got Invalid guest state in VMX enter

Tags: linux, x86, virtualization

I am testing intel VMX with a self-made VMM, and i hit an 'invalid guest state' when call 'vmlaunch'.
This error only happened when I re-run the VM after injected an external interrupt to the VM.
The VMM starting VM is as follows,
1. call VMXON,
2. init VMXON/VMCS regions,
3. start the VM (from real mode to protected mode)
4. vm exit,
5. call VMXOFF, and destroy VMXON/VMCS regions.

Below is the external interrupt handler.

```
isr_common_stub:
    ## 1. Save CPU state
    pusha ## Pushes edi,esi,ebp,esp,ebx,edx,ecx,eax
    mov %ds, %eax ## Lower 16-bits of eax = ds.
    push %eax ## save the data segment descriptor
    mov $0x10, %eax  ## kernel data segment descriptor
    mov %eax, %ds
    mov %eax, %es
    mov %eax, %fs
    mov %eax, %gs

    ## 2. Call C handler
    call isr_handler

    ## 3. Restore state
    pop %eax
    mov %eax, %ds
    mov %eax, %es
    mov %eax, %fs
    mov %eax, %gs
    popa
    add $8, %esp ## Cleans up the pushed error code and pushed ISR number
    sti
    iret ## pops 5 things at once: CS, EIP, EFLAGS, SS, and ESP

isr100:
    cli
    push $0
    push $100
    jmp isr_common_stub
```

Here is the VMCS dump when hit invalid guest state error.

```
[86429.875904]  # GUEST_ES_SEL = 0x0
[86429.875905]  # GUEST_CS_SEL = 0x0
[86429.875905]  # GUEST_SS_SEL = 0x0
[86429.875906]  # GUEST_DS_SEL = 0x0
[86429.875907]  # GUEST_FS_SEL = 0x0
[86429.875907]  # GUEST_GS_SEL = 0x0
[86429.875908]  # GUEST_LDTR_SEL = 0x0
[86429.875908]  # GUEST_TR_SEL = 0x0
[86429.875909]  # GUEST_INTERRUPT_STATUS = 0x0
[86429.876003]  # GUEST_PHYSICAL_ADDR_FULL = 0x0
[86429.876004]  # GUEST_PHYSICAL_ADDR_HIGH = 0x0
[86429.876006]  # VMCS_LINK_PTR_FULL = 0xffffffffffffffff
[86429.876007]  # VMCS_LINK_PTR_HIGH = 0xffffffff
[86429.876009]  # GUEST_IA32_DEBUGCTL_FULL = 0x0
[86429.876010]  # GUEST_IA32_DEBUGCTL_HIGH = 0x0
[86429.876012]  # GUEST_IA32_PAT_FULL = 0x0
[86429.876013]  # GUEST_IA32_PAT_HIGH = 0x0
[86429.876015]  # GUEST_IA32_EFER_FULL = 0x0
[86429.876017]  # GUEST_IA32_EFER_HIGH = 0x0
[86429.876018]  # GUEST_IA32_PERF_CTL_FULL = 0x0
[86429.876020]  # GUEST_IA32_PERF_CTL_HIGH = 0x0
[86429.876020]  # GUEST_PDPTE0_FULL = 0x0
[86429.876021]  # GUEST_PDPTE0_HIGH = 0x0
[86429.876022]  # GUEST_PDPTE1_FULL = 0x0
[86429.876022]  # GUEST_PDPTE1_HIGH = 0x0
[86429.876023]  # GUEST_PDPTE2_FULL = 0x0
[86429.876024]  # GUEST_PDPTE2_HIGH = 0x0
[86429.876025]  # GUEST_PDPTE3_FULL = 0x0
[86429.876025]  # GUEST_PDPTE3_HIGH = 0x0
[86429.876067]  # EXIT_INTERRUPT_INFO = 0x0
[86429.876067]  # EXIT_INTERRUPT_ERRCODE = 0x0
[86429.876068]  # IDT_VECTORING_INFO_FIELD = 0x0
[86429.876069]  # IDT_VECTORING_ERRCODE = 0x0
[86429.876069]  # EXIT_INSTR_LEN = 0x0
[86429.876070]  # INSTR_INFO = 0x0
[86429.876070]  # GUEST_ES_LIMIT = 0xffff
[86429.876071]  # GUEST_CS_LIMIT = 0xffff
[86429.876072]  # GUEST_SS_LIMIT = 0xffff
[86429.876072]  # GUEST_DS_LIMIT = 0xffff
[86429.876073]  # GUEST_FS_LIMIT = 0xffff
[86429.876074]  # GUEST_GS_LIMIT = 0xffff
[86429.876075]  # GUEST_LDTR_LIMIT = 0xffff
[86429.876075]  # GUEST_TR_LIMIT = 0xffff
[86429.876076]  # GUEST_GDTR_LIMIT = 0xffff
[86429.876077]  # GUEST_IDTR_LIMIT = 0xffff
[86429.876077]  # GUEST_ES_ATTR = 0x93
[86429.876078]  # GUEST_CS_ATTR = 0x9b
[86429.876078]  # GUEST_SS_ATTR = 0x93
[86429.876079]  # GUEST_DS_ATTR = 0x93
[86429.876080]  # GUEST_FS_ATTR = 0x93
[86429.876080]  # GUEST_GS_ATTR = 0x93
[86429.876081]  # GUEST_LDTR_ATTR = 0x82
[86429.876081]  # GUEST_TR_ATTR = 0x8b
[86429.876082]  # GUEST_INTERRUPTIBILITY_INFO = 0x0
[86429.876084]  # GUEST_ACTIVITY_STATE = 0x0
[86429.876085]  # GUEST_SMBASE = 0x0
[86429.876086]  # GUEST_IA32_SYSENTER_CS = 0x0
[86429.876087]    # vmread(0x482E) failed
[86429.876088]    # RFLAGS: 0x242
[86429.876088]  # GUEST_PREEMTION_TIMER          INVALID_VALUE
[86429.876090]  # HOST_IA32_SYSENTER_CS = 0x10
[86429.876092]  # CR0_MASK = 0xfffffffffffffff0
[86429.876093]  # CR4_MASK = 0xfffffffffffff871
[86429.876095]  # CR0_READ_SHADOW = 0x60000010
[86429.876096]  # CR4_READ_SHADOW = 0x10
[86429.876097]  # CR3_TARGET_0 = 0x0
[86429.876099]  # CR3_TARGET_1 = 0x23341e000
[86429.876101]  # CR3_TARGET_2 = 0x0
[86429.876102]  # CR3_TARGET_3 = 0x0
[86429.876103]  # EXIT_QUALIFICATION = 0x0
[86429.876104]  # IO_RCX = 0x0
[86429.876104]  # IO_RSI = 0x0
[86429.876105]  # IO_RDI = 0x0
[86429.876105]  # IO_RIP = 0x0
[86429.876106]  # GUEST_LINEAR_ADDR = 0x0
[86429.876108]  # GUEST_CR0 = 0x50032
[86429.876108]  # GUEST_CR3 = 0x0
[86429.876109]  # GUEST_CR4 = 0x2050
[86429.876110]  # GUEST_ES_BASE = 0x0
[86429.876110]  # GUEST_CS_BASE = 0x0
[86429.876111]  # GUEST_SS_BASE = 0x0
[86429.876111]  # GUEST_DS_BASE = 0x0
[86429.876112]  # GUEST_FS_BASE = 0x0
[86429.876112]  # GUEST_GS_BASE = 0x0
[86429.876113]  # GUEST_LDTR_BASE = 0x0
[86429.876114]  # GUEST_TR_BASE = 0x0
[86429.876114]  # GUEST_GDTR_BASE = 0x0
[86429.876115]  # GUEST_IDTR_BASE = 0x0
[86429.876117]  # GUEST_DR7 = 0x400
[86429.876118]  # GUEST_RSP = 0x7bfa
[86429.876118]  # GUEST_RIP = 0x7c00
[86429.876119]  # GUEST_RFLAGS = 0x2
[86429.876120]  # GUEST_PENDING_DEBUG_EXCEPT = 0x0
[86429.876120]  # GUEST_IA32_SYSENTER_ESP = 0x0
[86429.876121]  # GUEST_IA32_SYSENTER_EIP = 0x0
```

After I reload the VMM, the VM can run well.
But hit the same error, if i re-run the VM.

Comment: Can you clarify the sequence. To your steps 1 - 5, please add a) where the interrupt occurs; b) where the vm entry failure occurs; c) any other steps in between those events.

Comment: In the VMCS dump, I don’t see processor controls, secondary controls, entry controls, and entry interruption information.

Comment: It’s not clear whether you are trying to inject an interrupt into the guest (I guess you’re not), but if you are, IF must be 1 in guest rflags.

Comment: The only reliable way to figure out this problem is to go through all of the checks listed in the SDM one by one and check them by hand to see which one(s) fail. You will need the values of the VMX MSRs as well as the contents of the VMCS to do all the checks.

Comment: You are right, i did check the VMCS fields, and found the entry_interrupt_info field is non-zero, when the VM is re-start. By clearing it to 0, VM can run well.